# Preserve newlines when setting html in a div from a textarea - Jquery

Tags: jquery, newline

I got this little html -:

```
<div id="viewOne"></div>
<textarea id="viewTwo"></textarea>
<button id="copyToDiv" value="Copy to Div"></button>
```

This is my Jquery snippet-:

```
$("#copyToDiv").on("click",function(){ $("#viewOne").html( $("#viewTwo").val() ) });
```

But it strips of `new line characters` from textarea's val and what i get is string with new lines stripped off. How do I preserve newlines when setting the html of div.
Thanks a lot for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new lines are preserved, but not converted to HTML new lines (`<BR/>`), so they are ignored.

You can convert them to `<BR/>` with `.replace`:

```
$("#copyToDiv").on("click",function(){ $("#viewOne").html( $("#viewTwo").val().replace("\n","<br/>") ) });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tasos Bitsios.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="viewOne" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></div>
<textarea id="viewTwo"></textarea>
<button id="copyToDiv" value="Copy to Div"></button>
```

`white-space: pre-wrap;` tells the element to preserve newline and other whitespace characters and actually answers this old question.